# Android build: encoding when embedding properties in BuildConfig

Tags: android, gradle

I'm embedding properties from `gradle.properties` in BuildConfig:

gradle.properties:

```
FIELD=value
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "FIELD", project.properties["FIELD"]
    }
}
```

This works mostly fine. My problem is that it looks like the value is copy and pasted into the generated `BuildConfig` class, so it doesn't handle numeric values or empty values.

I end up seeing things like this in the generated code:

```
public static final String FIELD = ;
```

or

```
public static final String FIELD = 1234;
```

What's the right way encode this so that values in the properties file get encoded as strings and not just pasted in?

Edit: this seems to be a solution, but I'd rather not have to use commons-lang just to get this, and it feels like there should be a better way to accomplish this:

```
buildConfigField 'String', 'FIELD',
    $/"${StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava((project.properties['FIELD'] ?: '') as String)}"/$
```

Comment: Since Gradle is Groovy, you should be able to use string interpolation: `buildConfigField "String", "FIELD", "$project.properties['FIELD']"`.

Comment: True, but the parameter passed to buildConfigField is still an unencoded string.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm not thinking straight. I think I wound up using `'"'+project.properties['FIELD']+'"'` elsewhere. There's probably an escaping option that works with string interpolation, such as `"\"$project.properties['FIELD']\""`. Or use a slashy-string: `/"$project.properties['FIELD']"/` -- see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_slashy_string.